# the eigenvalues of matrix with a real number as the diagonal and 1 around it

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question I'm trying to solve and have some intuition but need help with framing and formalizing it.

I have a matrix $$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
 d&  1&  1&...&1\\ 
 1&  d&  1&...   &1\\ 
 1&  1&  d& ...&1\\ 
 1&  1&  1& d&1\\ 
 1&  1&  1& ...&d
\end{pmatrix}$$

I am trying to show that the eigenvector is

$ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\ 
 1 \\ 
 1 \\ 
 1 \\ 
 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ and  $ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\ 
 0 \\ 
 0 \\ 
 0 \\ 
 -1 
\end{pmatrix}$

And that the eigenvalue is $d+n*1$ and $d-1$

I understand that the eigenvalues are the $det(tI - A)$ and proving that the characteristic polynomial roots are the eigenvalues works well with a 2x2 and 3x3 matrix, however, I need to scale this up and make it general, and need help with formulating that.

Also, the eigenvector is $Av = \lambda v$, and when the eigenvector is 
 $ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\ 
 1 \\ 
 1 \\ 
 1 \\ 
 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ I can see why the eigenvalue of $d+(n*1)$ is what it is, but I need to show it, can I please have some help?

Comment: You mean $\begin{pmatrix}1& 0& 0& 0 &-1\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: yes, that is right, typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, let

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
 d&  1&  1&1&1\\ 
 1&  d&  1&1   &1\\ 
 1&  1&  d& 1&1\\ 
 1&  1&  1& d&1\\ 
 1&  1&  1& 1&d
\end{pmatrix}$$

$ det(tI-A) = \left| \begin{pmatrix}
 t-d& - 1& - 1&-1&-1\\ 
 -1&  t - d& - 1&-1   &-1\\ 
 -1& - 1&  t- d& -1&-1\\ 
 -1& - 1&  -1& t- d&-1\\ 
 -1& - 1&  -1&- 1&t- d
\end{pmatrix} \right| $

$\ \left| \begin{pmatrix}
 t-d-4& t-d- 4&t-d - 4&t-d-4&t-d-4\\ 
 -1&  t - d& - 1&-1   &-1\\ 
 -1& - 1&  t- d& -1&-1\\ 
 -1& - 1&  -1& t- d&-1\\ 
 -1& - 1&  -1&- 1&t- d
\end{pmatrix} \right| $ (adding all the rows to the first row)

$ = (t-d-4)  \left| \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 1&1&1&1\\ 
 -1&  t - d& - 1&-1   &-1\\ 
 -1& - 1&  t- d& -1&-1\\ 
 -1& - 1&  -1& t- d&-1\\ 
 -1& - 1&  -1&- 1&t- d
\end{pmatrix} \right|$
$  = (t-d-4)  \left| \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 1&1&1&1\\ 
 0&  t - d+1& 0&0   &0\\ 
 0& 0&  t- d+1& 0&0\\ 
 0& 0&  0& t- d+1&0\\ 
 0& 0&  0&0&t- d+1
\end{pmatrix} \right|$ (adding first row the all other rows)
$=(t-d-4)(t-d+1)^4  $

Comment: how does this work, if $(t-d-4)$ is a constant, then how can one factor it from only the first row?

Comment: Determinant function is linear for each row.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to explicitly compute $\det(A - tI)$ if you already know the eigenvectors.  Here's one way to prove what you need:

Note that 
$$
Ay = \langle y,x\rangle x + (d-1) y
$$
Where $x = (1,1,\dots,1)$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denotes the dot product.

What can we say when $y = x$?  What if $y$ is orthogonal to $x$?  This analysis should allow you to find $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors (and their associated eigenvalues).

Comment: you mean $Ay = \langle y,x\rangle x + (d-1)\cdot y$?

Comment: Yes, good catch.

Comment: Had to say this is a much better way, ;-)

Comment: Omomomomom, but if I take the dot product of say $\begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\ 
 1 \\ 
 1 \\ 
 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ as y to x(the eigenvalue) and add d-1 dot product y, then I don't reach a solution where $Ay = \lambda x$

Comment: $d-1$ is a scalar; $\cdot$ is not a dot-product.  Plugging in that $y$ (that is, $y=x$) yields
$$
Ay = Ax = \langle x,x \rangle x + (d-1)\cdot x = 
4 \cdot x + (d - 1) \cdot x = 
(d + 3) \cdot x = (d+3)y
$$
So indeed, $Ay = \lambda y$ with $\lambda = d+3$.